# How to use clang ast matcher to match a typedef

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree, clang-static-analyzer, clang-ast-matchers

I'm writing a checker for clang-tidy, which checks cast between int and pointer.

for example, for code:

```
int val = 0xbaddeef;
char* ptr = (char*)val;
```

I want to fix it to:

```
char* ptr = (char*)(uintptr_t)val;
```

But if `a` is already `uintptr_t`, I don't fix it.

```
typedef uintptr_t myType;
myType val = 0xbaddeef;
char* ptr = (char*)val;
```

My question is that I matched the `CStyleCastExpr` and get the match result, but I can't get the source type of the cast, I use `CStyleCastExpr.getSubExpr().getType().getXXXXType()`, I get the type of `val` is  `myType` or `long/int`, but not `uintptr_t`.

how can I know `val` is a type of `uintptr_t`?

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at getType().getAsString(), getType().getCanonicalType.getAsString(), and getType().getUnqualifiedType.getAsString(). I think one of them will return what you want.